# Is this Proof Involving Cardinal Arithmetic Correct?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

**Question**

Show that for $n>0$,

$n.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}=\aleph _0.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}= 2^{\aleph _0}.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}= 2^{2^{\aleph _0}}.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}=(2^{2^{\aleph _0}})^n=(2^{2^{\aleph _0}})^{\aleph _0}= (2^{2^{\aleph _0}})^{2^{\aleph _0}}=2^{2^{\aleph _0}}.$

**Attempt**

$2^{2^{\aleph_ 0}}\leq n.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}\leq {\aleph _0}.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}\leq 2^{\aleph _0}.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}\leq 2^{2^{\aleph _0}}.2^{2^{\aleph _0}}=2^{2^{\aleph _0}+2^{\aleph _0}}=(2^{2.2^{\aleph _0}})=(2^{2^1.2^{\aleph _0}})=2^{2^{1+\aleph _0}}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$

I feel know this can be done with about three sequences of inequalities. So, I am not sure of the fourth inequality. Also, I think some things may be missing, as I am not completely confident of this. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof looks right, as long as you are allowed to use the properties about cardinal operations you used.

Comment: Is $n$ restricted to natural numbers? If it can be larger cardinals, then this fails when $n > 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. The particular facts you used are: $\le$ is reflexive and transitive on cardinals, $\alpha \le \beta \implies \alpha\gamma \le \beta\gamma$, $n > 0 \implies 1 \le n$, $n \le \aleph_0$, $\alpha \le 2^\alpha$, $2^\alpha2^\beta = 2^{\alpha + \beta}$, $\alpha + \alpha = 2\alpha$, $2 = 2^1$, $1 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$. If all of these *for cardinals* have been covered already, then you are okay.

Comment: That should have been "anti-symmetric and transitive".